# can't get value of dynamic remove/edit HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to write a piece of code that can handle remove or editing of dynamic HTML table. I've googled and stackoverflow this problem, I see many samples but none of them worked properly.

Here is my code:

server.js

```
router.get('/bookShow', (req, res) => {
    bookModel.find({isDeleted : false}).sort('-pageCount').exec((err, data) => {
        if (data) {
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});
```

BookModel in Database:

[image]

bookShow.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $.getJSON('/bookShow', (json) => {
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + "<button class='deleteButton'>" + "<i class='material-icons'>delete</i></button>" + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + "<button class='editButton'>" + "<i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button>" + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].pageCount + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>")
                $('table').append(tr);
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', () => {
            console.log($(this));
        })
    });  
</script>
```

**Problem:** As it seen in `bookShow.html`, I've declared an eventlistener whenever `.deleteButton` clicked. But I can't access the other fields of that table row. for example when I click on delete button of Behzad, I can't be notified the book name and its page count.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using ES6's **Arrow function** `() => {}` the `this` is not any more what you're used to like by using `function`. It's `window`, because of their nature of lexical scope binding. Not any more the jQuery's representation of the DOM Element "`this`".

> `$(this)` =
>   *jQuery.fn.init [Window]*  by usign Arrow function `() => {}`
>   *jQuery.fn.init [button.deleteButton]* by using Function `function () {}`

so your solution would be to use the standard `$(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function() {`

or to add the `click` on button creation - which is doable by making your button an *live* in-memory jQuery element `$('<button>', {on:{click(){}}, appendTo:'selector'})` instead of HTML string literal.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Here's a remake:

```js
const json = [ // You use getJSON, I'll use this for my demo
{"name": "King of the Jungle","pageCount": 543},
{"name": "The Things I've Done","pageCount": 198}
];

jQuery($ => {

  // $.getJSON

  $('table').append(json.map((book, i) => 
    $('<tr>', {
      html: `
        <td>${i+1}</td>
        <td>${book.name}</td>
        <td>${book.pageCount}</td>
      `,
      append: [       // or use prepend
        $('<td>', {
          append: $('<button>', {
            class: "buttonEdit",
            html: "<i class='material-icons'>edit</i>",
            on: {
              click() { // Same as using `click: function () {`
                console.log(`Editing ${book.name} by:`, this); // this = <button>
              }
            }
          })
        }),
        $('<td>', {
          append: $('<button>', {
            class: "buttonDelete",
            html: "<i class='material-icons'>delete</i>",
            on: {
              click() {
                console.log(`Deleting ${book.name} by:`, this);
              }
            }
          })
        }),        
      ]
    })
  ));

  // END $.getJSON

});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: woow! what an amazing thing! 
I can't access the name and pagecount yet! do you have any solution for that?
thank you very very much

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi given that you *do have* a correct access to your JSON file (meaning that you have no issue with that part) - I'll show you soon an example on how I'd structure the code

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi added an example

Comment: finally it works. I'm so pleased for you complete and perfect answer <3 .